# Effect of including a header file in C

Tags: c, file, header

What is the effect of including a header file, none of the functions declared in which, are used in source file ? Does it affect stack size etc ?

Answer (score 6):

It will have no effect, but it will increase compilation time and make the code harder to understand and maintain. You should only include the headers you actually need, and remove those which become redundant.

Comment: Could you please explain why it increases compile time? Is it due to the additional pre-processing overhead?

Answer (score 6):

That depends on whether there are *definitions* in the header file or just *declarations.*

> It also depends entirely on the implementation since the ISO C standard has nothing to say about how things are done at that level. It only covers how things appear to behave at a "C virtual machine" level. But I'll cover the most likely scenario here.

Definitions such as `int xyzzy;` (or, worse, `char big_honkin_thing[9999999];`) may take up space in the object file and, unless you have a particularly clever linker, the executable as well. I say "may" since this is dependent on the implementation.

Initialising the value is more likely to ensure it's stored in the object rather than created at runtime. But you're likely to find an effect regardless of that, either larger object/executable files if it's created at compile time or (mildly) slower startup times as more memory has to be zero-initialised.

For example, adding `char big[99999] = {'x'};` to a header file results in the size of the executable going from 18K to 118K.

Simple declaration stuff like `typedef` and `extern` will not allocate space in the object in and of themselves.

In addition, even *without* definitions, the compile time will be increased since the compiler has to process that header file. But that will not have any impact on runtime (either speed or storage) itself.

Comment: Good point; but `char big_honkin_thing[9999999];` will likely take no space in the binary (since it's not initialized).

Comment: @cnicutar, yes it will. Static storage duration objects are initialised to all zeros. As I said, you may have a smart linker that realises it's not used and removes it from the executable but that would be true of explicitly initialised things as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo `.bss`. I don't think it's about the linker detecting unused stuff (btw `ld` doesn't detect anything). It's about `.bss` vs `.data`.

Comment: @cnicutar, sorry, I stand corrected. Some compilers will be smart enough to allocate zero-init stuff at runtime rather than storing it in the object file. I'll update the answer but that's an implementation issue rather than a C one (and, in any case, that's still an effect, albeit a time one rather than a space one).

Comment: Very true. The question is if definitions have any place in a header file. Except for some very specific corner cases, I would consider that an error or at least a strong code smell.

Answer (score 4):

The stack size is determined by your linker.  Presumably you actually mean whether or not the emitted code is larger or not.

Including a header file whose declarations are never referenced in that translation unit will not affect the size of the generated objects.  Of course, it will slow down compilation.

Comment: Even if the declarations are not referenced, does that increase the **size** of the **Translation Unit**? Obviously it won't affect the final object size, as you mention.

Answer (score 2):

It will increase compile times, but AFAIK there shouldn't be any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Directly accessing the source file compare to accessing source file with header file will take less time if in the case there is nothing in header which can effect the source file.